# I have an error with min and max nextInt

Tags: java

I want to make the speed on vector x random with min -5 and max 5. Everytime I run the game it is crashing.
the problem in random because when i set velX = 2 or 3 it works perfectly, help me  please.
(Sorry for my english, i hope you understand me)

```
velX = random.nextInt(5 - -5) + -5;
```

Comment: `5 - -5` is subtracting negative 5 from 5. It's not a range.

Comment: (If you *meant* to write a subtraction there, well, it's kind of a weird way to go about that.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
velX = random.nextInt(10) - 5;
```

(Generate a random int btw `0` and `10`, then subtract `5`, giving you a range btw `-5` (inclusive) and `5` (exclusive). If you want `5` to be inclusive as well, change the `nextInt()` parameter to `11`.

---

OTOH you probably shouldn't use a real random, but rather a bell curve (values in the middle appearing more often than outliers). One easy way to achieve that is to have a List with all the values (once for outliers and more often for middle values) and pick randomly among them. You might want to play around with the values to see what works best for you.

```
// do this only once, during initialization
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add(-5);
values.addAll(Collections.nCopies(2, -4));
values.addAll(Collections.nCopies(3, -3));
values.addAll(Collections.nCopies(5, -2));
values.addAll(Collections.nCopies(8, -1));
values.addAll(Collections.nCopies(12, 0));
values.addAll(Collections.nCopies(8, 1));
values.addAll(Collections.nCopies(5, 2));
values.addAll(Collections.nCopies(3, 3));
values.addAll(Collections.nCopies(2, 4));
values.add(5);

// do this every time
velX = values.get(random.nextInt(values.size()));
```

Comment: i just want to make velX to be between -5 and 5, can someone write to me how exactly i need to do?

Comment: velX = random.nextInt(10) - 5 is the same with this velX = random.nextInt(5 - -5) + -5; or not ?

Comment: the first part of my answer gives you exactly what you want

Comment: the game crashes again, can you explain me why?

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sp.main.Game.update(Game.java:91)
 at com.sp.main.Game.run(Game.java:71)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

this is my error